# Set the DbParameter.DbType of a null value in a generic way?

Tags: c#, sql, null, varbinarymax

I've got a problem with SQL update statements when I pass null values
(or better let's say DbNull values) to a DbParameter object.
When I pass the DbNull value to the Value property, the DbType of the
DbParameter object is still STRING.

If I try to write into a binary field ( varbinary(max) ), I got an exception that the conversion between **varchar** and **varbinary** is not possible. So in that case I have to set the DbType by my own. My question is now, how do I get the DbType from an
.Net type. I want to be this generic, so I can use my methods with other
databases. I couldn't find anything usefull in the MSDN documentation.
If someone can get me some hints how to solve this, I would appreciate
this. Or maybe I'm on the wrong path. I'm not sure for the moment.

Comment: Straightforward solution is to use switch(dbType) manually for type you're using

Comment: When an objects value is null you can not get the type of the object thus I can not set the DbType. Its a dead end street...

Comment: @Dissy you speak of the default in the switch/case ? How would you use the switch case? I will show you bit of my code and I dont think my approach works with your suggestion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing I can suggest there is to use a generic method to add the parameter, i.e.

```
... Foo<T>(T value, ...)
```

That way, you can check `typeof(T)` even if `value` is `null`. You would then need to switch on the type of `T` and hard-code the relationship. A `switch` on `Type.GetTypeCode(...)` makes things fairly easy.

Another approach is to pass the values in as typed members - for example, in dapper we pass the parameters in as a wrapper object (typically an anonymous type) - then we can inspect the types from the `MemberInfo`s.

Comment: Thanks Marc just wanted to post a sample but I think its not needed. I also thought about making the CreateParameter<T>(T value,String marker). I dont think nobody knows better than you in that area around this time ;-)